# how to specify model name while parsing message using http parse post request in rasa2.0?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

api: model/parse, type: post. In this new rasa2.0 I'm not able to find a way to provide model name while parsing request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since 1.0, the Rasa server doesn't load multiple models at a time, so there is only one model to make a prediction.

If you want a parse result from a different model from the one you have loaded, you first have to replace the loaded model, see https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/pages/http-api#operation/replaceModel